# @SecondaryTables : Mapping one entity to several tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I know very well that ***@SecondaryTable*** annotation is to map the ***fields of a single entity to several tables***, exactly as if those tables were merged into a single one.
I am facing problem in implementing this concept.
There are 3 classes which needs to be persisted,

***Class1 whose 2 fields out of 4 are going to be stored in 2 other different tables***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_CAT")
@SecondaryTables({

    @SecondaryTable(name = "CAT_1", pkJoinColumns = {
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CAT1_PK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        }),
    @SecondaryTable(name = "CAT_2", uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"storyPart2"})
    })
})
public class Cat {

    @Id@GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String catName;

    @Column(table = "CAT_1")
    private String storyPart1; // this field is going to be stored in CAT_1

    @Column(table = "CAT_2")
    private String storyPart2; // and so on
    // getters and setters
}
```

***Class 2: This class when persisted will store storyPart1 field of above persisted class***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAT_1")
public class CatOne {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CAT1_PK")
    private Long CAT1_PK;

    @Column(name = "CATNAME_1")
    private String catName1;

    @Column(name = "CATAGE_1")
    private String catAge1;
    // getters and setters
}
```

***Class 3: This class when persisted will store storyPart2 field of persisted Class 1***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAT_2")
public class CatTwo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CATNAME_2")
    private String catName2;

    @Column(name = "CATAGE_2")
    private String catAge2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The 3 tables created in the Database are:

***For Class 1:***

```
CREATE TABLE main_cat
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  catname character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT main_cat_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

***For Class 2:***

```
CREATE TABLE cat_1
(
  storypart1 character varying(255),
  cat1_pk bigint NOT NULL,
  catage_1 character varying(255),
  catname_1 character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT cat_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cat1_pk),
  CONSTRAINT fk_kvtvo6nrv78wxkm0kv01k9kdq FOREIGN KEY (cat1_pk)
      REFERENCES main_cat (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

***For Class 3:***

```
CREATE TABLE cat_2
(
  storypart2 character varying(255),
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  catage_2 character varying(255),
  catname_2 character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT cat_2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_2duj6ebg3504x18mlw2xkpvg6 FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES main_cat (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uk_5ko8732qslvvx98gy0q666qrf UNIQUE (storypart2)
)
```

The problem is that instead of inserting a record in CAT_1, it fires 2 inserts for the same. The same thing happens for the record to be inserted in CAT_2.

```
         Cat cat = new Cat();

         cat.setCatName("CAT Name");
         cat.setStoryPart1("STORYPART1");
         cat.setStoryPart2("STORYPART2");

         CatOne catOne = new CatOne();

         catOne.setCatAge1("10");
         catOne.setCatName1("catName1");

         CatTwo catTwo = new CatTwo();

         catTwo.setCatAge2("12");
         catTwo.setCatName2("catName2");

         session.save(cat);
         session.save(catOne);
         session.save(catTwo);
```

***Statements:***

```
Hibernate: insert into CAT_1 (storyPart1, CAT1_PK) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CAT_1 (CATAGE_1, CATNAME_1, CAT1_PK) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Due to the splitting of a single insert statement into 2 statement, Hibernate throws this error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update 
on table "cat_1" violates foreign key constraint 
"fk_kvtvo6nrv78wxkm0kv01k9kdq" Detail: Key (cat1_pk)=(2) is not 
present in table "main_cat".
```

Looks like i have implemented the @SecondaryTable concept in a wrong manner. How to make Hibernate fire a single insert in this case then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already use some table as entity's secondary table, then it is not a good idea to also map that table to another entity. Secondary table should be understood as simply another table for given entity, which will be managed only through that entity.

If you already have an entity on secondary table, then use regular entity mappings `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`, etc.

Comment: There was no need for these, session.save(catOne);
         session.save(catTwo);